# jQuery: fadeIn() after hide('slide')

Tags: jquery, hide, fade

I want a div to slide out of the viewport and then fadeIn at the same spot with a different background image. This only slides it out:

```
$('#myDiv').hide('slide').queue(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(images/picB.png)'});
    $(this).fadeIn();
}
```

The `hide('slide')` eventually causes the div to be set to `display: none;`, the position will be restored to where it was before. What do I have to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget [`.dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/)!

When you [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) a function, you *must* call `.dequeue` to inform jQuery that the function has completed.

Your current function is adding `.fadeIn` to the queue, but since your queued function never "completes", it is never called.

```
$('#myDiv').hide('slide').queue(function() {
    $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(images/picB.png)'})
           .fadeIn()
           .dequeue(); //Tell jQuery to do the fade
});
```

Comment: This is working right the way I want it to. Thank you :-) I didn't know about the dequeue to call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/f42dsjb2/

```
$('#myDiv').hide('slide').queue(function() {   
    $(this).show('slide').css({"background":"red"}).dequeue();
});
```

Comment: This is not quite what I want to have. The difficulty seemed to be that a new fadeIn() doesn't work without a show() (after it has been hidden). But the dequeue() was crucial, too. Thanks for the helpful fiddle.